# CERoundProgressView set maximum value less than 1.0

Tags: objective-c, ios6

Is there any way to set the maximum value of a `CERoundProgressView` object to be less than 1.0 - something like 0.5?

Reference: [CERoundProgressView](https://github.com/Ceroce/CERoundProgressView)

Comment: There should not be a need to do this, that I can think of. Whatever you are measuring progress of can be made into a percentage (between `0.0` and `1.0`). If the max value of something you are measuring progress of is `0.5`, take the current value of progress, `x`, and divide it by `0.5` to get the percent complete. For example, if `x=0.25`, then your progress is `x/0.5 = 0.25/0.5 = 0.5`

Comment: Why max a progress to half?  You should be setting the current progress to current unit / total number of units.  The progress is always relative to the 'whole' of a collection of units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always subclass CERoundProgressView, add properties for max and min.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) float max;
@property (nonatomic, weak) float min;
```

set max to 0.5, set min to be 0.1 if you want

Then, override `setProgress:(float)progress animated:(BOOL)animated;` with something like this:

```
- (void) setProgress:(float)progress animated:(BOOL)animated {
    float value = ((progress - self.min) / (self.max - self.min) ) * (1.0 - 0.0);
    [super setProgress:value animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: So what does the `value` float do if you don't mind me asking? It represents the amount for which the progress increases? And what's the point of `(1.0 - 0.0)` - it just multiplies it by 1, right?

Comment: Yes, so the (1.0 - 0.0) isn't necessary, that just represents the range you are converting to. Value represents the progress passed in, converted to be in between 1 and 0. As long as progress is between self.min and self.max, value will come out between 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no property to alter the range of the progress. However, since this project is opensource, you can easily adjust the class to use simple linear interpolation.